# HTTPS GET REST request in c# is not working with RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, https

I can successfully invoke an HTTPS REST GET request by using postman.

But when I am trying to invoke the same HTTPS REST request by using RestShap (C#, .NET) with the following code.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://testsite.com:7000/abcd/1.0/xyx/games/getgames");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("myusername", "mypassword");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am getting the following exception

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

I have tried to capture the request using Fiddler, What I can observe a strange thing is that the request type is HTTP.

The error from the fiddler is

> fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to testsite.com (for #45)
>   failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Is the decrypt HTTPS option turned on in fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SSL certificate to consume the https request, you can add SSL certificate to your request using following code

```
X509Certificate2 certificates = new X509Certificate2();
certificates.Import(...);

client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection(){certificate});
```

Comment: Does the restsharp handle the certificate automatically by identifying the HTTPS part of the url?

Comment: How do we create a certificate for using RestSharp. After creating do we need to install it in to windows or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688128/ssl-certificates-for-just-api-or-do-clients-need-them-to