# Shall I have client certificates for consumers of my REST API?

Tags: c#, python, rest, api, ssl

I have a REST API which uses JWT bearer authentication over HTTPS. SSL certificate is installed on the web server hosting my REST API. Do I need to provide client certificates to **different applications(users)** who want to consume my API, to have a handshake between their server and my server using the client certificate which i provide them.

I tried calling my HTTPS REST API which I developed in C# from a python script running locally from my machine but I had to specify the verify flag to False or `ssl.CERT_NONE` for the call to succeed

```
import requests

requests.get('some https url', verify=False)
```

I know we can also use self signed certificates. I am worried about **Man in the Middle** attacks if they call my endpoint with `verify=False` and If someone tries to use my API in his app which is in production over https do I need to give him the client certificate for handshake or his app would be able to call my https api endpoint without me specifically providing a client certificate.

I tried to take some leads from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688128/ssl-certificates-for-just-api-or-do-clients-need-them-to) but it doesn't explain how different users whose apps are trying to call my endpoint over https, will be able to perform a handshake with my rest api

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: keep your private key file safe and you wont have any problems.

The long answer has to do with explaining asymmetrical encryption and how its implemented in a TLS handshake. When a client opens a HTTPS connection with your server a series of requests are sent back and forth:

1. Client sends HELLO
2. Server sends HELLO back including the servers SSL certificate
3. Client verifies the certificate with the certificate authority
4. The client sends back a random string of bytes encrypted with the servers **public key**
5. The server decrypts the string using the **private key**

After the final step a session is created between the client and server. In order for a man-in-the-middle attack to be successful the "man in the middle" needs to have your private key and proxy every action just described back to your server, otherwise one of the steps will fail and the client will get that "SERVER UNVERIFIED" error in their browser warning them that the connection is not secure.

This is a pretty brief explanation of the process, you can do some more reading [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Joe, does that mean I don’t have to share client certificates with users who want to consume my API.

Comment: Nope, you wont have to.

Comment: A small query again. If my users use it with verify=False in their local environments would there be a TLS handshake in that scenario or the channel would be susceptible to attacks?

Comment: how does that answer the question?